# Updating ActiveRecord in Rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm writing my first Rails 'Store' app and I'm coming across something weird in one of my tests. I'm trying to test the add_product method on cart.rb:

```
    class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy

  def add_product(product)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product.id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(:product_id => product.id, :price => product.price)      
    end
    current_item
  end

  def total_price 
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
  end

end
```

I'm testing that adding the same product to a cart twice increases the quantity rather than adding a new line (line_item). Here's the test:

```
test "line item quantity is increased when duplicate product is added" do
    cart = carts(:one)
    ruby_book = products(:ruby)

    cart.add_product(ruby_book)
    cart.save    
    assert_equal 1, cart.line_items(ruby_book).to_a.count

    cart.add_product(ruby_book)
    cart.save
    assert_equal 1, cart.line_items(ruby_book).to_a.count
    assert_equal 2, cart.line_items(ruby_book).first.quantity # fail!
  end
```

I get a fail on the last assert. The quantity is 1, where I expect 2. I've checked the test.log file and no update is ever run against my sqlite3 instance... I can add the log or the Fixtures files if necessary, but I'm sure this is such a newbie question that it won't be required!

Thanks in advance,

Stu

Comment: `cart.line_items(ruby_book)` is not correct.  I think you might want `cart.line_items.find_all_by_product_id(ruby_book.id)`.  That isn't directed at solving your problem.  Also, it looks like you could break up your one test into 2 or 3 separate tests.

Comment: Thanks @Wizard of Ogz

You're right there are too many asserts in there. I'm sure that cart.line_items(ruby_book) produces the same SQL as the alternative... I'll check that too, though.

Comment: I checked out your suggestion and it's spot-on @Wizard of Ogz - much appreciated.

For anyone following this, the sql generated for my line did not limit to a product_id at all:

SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE ("line_items".cart_id = 980190962)

The only reason it worked it that there were no other users who also had a cart!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the line item's quantity attribute, but not saving the change.
Calling save on the parent won't save the children's attributes.
You can call save on current_item in the add_product method after the increment line.

```
if current_item
  current_item.quantity += 1
  current_item.save
else
```

Comment: Hi @simianarmy

Thanks - that worked.

The solution is bothering me, though. It seems odd that I now have to explicitly call .save in my test when adding the product for the first time, but I don't have to call it when adding an existing product because it's called in the 'else' clause on the add_product method.

Is there a nicer way to do this? I might now always know if the product is in there already or not...

Cheers, Stu

Comment: Ah - I just read your answer again. It's the **line_items** collection that I'm calling save on.

Cheers again